# Crash in ios 6 and later -[MKStoreManager provideContent:forReceipt:]

Tags: iphone, ios6, crash, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I have my app live which is non-consumable type.

App is crashing on iOS 6 and later. It is crashing on user's device but not on testing device.

Crash log says this:

```
Exception Type:  SIGTRAP  
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x3350316c  
Crashed Thread:  0  

Thread 0 Crashed:  
0   CoreFoundation                      0x3350316c _CFHash + 8  
1   CoreFoundation                      0x00002b50 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1892  
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33503a8b _CFDictionaryGetValue + 83  
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0004a7a7 -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSource setValue:forKey:] + 39  
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0004a723 _CFXPreferencesSetValue + 135  
5   CoreFoundation                      0x3354a601 _CFPreferencesSetAppValue + 41  
6   Foundation                          0x00009907 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 83  
7   myAppName                           0x00038287 -[MKStoreManager provideContent:forReceipt:] (MKStoreManager.m:311)  
8   myAppName                           0x000387b1 -[MKStoreObserver restoreTransaction:] (MKStoreObserver.m:88)  
9   myAppName                           0x000385e1 -[MKStoreObserver paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:] (MKStoreObserver.m:64)  
10  StoreKit                            0x0000404d __NotifyObserverAboutChanges + 85  
11  CoreFoundation                      0x3350874d _CFArrayApplyFunction + 177  
12  StoreKit                            0x00003fe9 -[SKPaymentQueue _notifyObserversAboutChanges:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 129  
13  StoreKit                            0x000048af -[SKPaymentQueue _processUpdates:trimUnmatched:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 999  
14  StoreKit                            0x00004f8d -[SKPaymentQueue _setTransactionsWithReply:] + 157  
15  StoreKit                            0x00003b8b __block_global_0 + 63  
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000211f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11  
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000014b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 23  
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000061bd _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 225  
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00095f3b __CFRunLoopRun + 1291  
20  CoreFoundation                      0x33508ebd _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357  
21  CoreFoundation                      0x33508d49 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105  
22  GraphicsServices                    0x370bb2eb _GSEventRunModal + 75  
23  UIKit                               0x3541e301 _UIApplicationMain + 1121  
24  myAppName                           0x0000260f main (main.m:20)
```

This app supports iOS 4.3 and later.

I have tried in many ways but can't find proper solution. Anyone have any idea how I resolve this? Should I use some other code for in-app purchase?

Comment: I am having the same issue with a live app. Would you possibly be able to share how you solved this problem? Thanks in advance if you can take the time...

Comment: Still struggling through this, I would love to hear how you solved it!

Comment: I'm also having a similar issue. Would be very interested in hearing how you solved this.

Comment: please follow following link as it helped me alot. http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/